# How to get the description and other fields from the MIB file, knowing the OID?

Tags: python, pysnmp, mib

With the help of the pysnmp library, I can find out the names by OID, but how do I find out the rest of the fields from the MIB file?

I get the name like this(label):

```
mibBuilder = builder.MibBuilder()
compiler.addMibCompiler(mibBuilder, sources=['/home/test/etc/mibs'])
mibBuilder.loadModules('IF-MIB', "CISCO-ENHANCED-MEMPOOL-MIB")
mibView = view.MibViewController(mibBuilder)

oid, label, suffix = mibView.getNodeName((1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 9, 9, 221, 1, 1, 1, 1, 26))
```

Comment: Please include your imports and an example of the current output and expected output.

Comment: If I run the command on the command line: 

'snmptranslate -M ./ -m ALL -Td 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.19.99999.4'  

I will get the following output: 

'CISCO-SMI::ciscoTDomainTcpIpv6
ciscoTDomainTcpIpv6 OBJECT-IDENTITY
  -- FROM       CISCO-SMI
  DESCRIPTION   "The TCP over IPv6 transport domain.  The corresponding
        transport address is of type CiscoTAddressIPv6 for global IPv6
        addresses and CiscoTAddressIPv6s for scoped IPv6 addresses." }'
How do I get the same data using the pysnmp library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `MibNode` object as showed in the example,

https://github.com/lextudio/pysnmp/blob/v6.0.5/examples/smi/manager/print-oid-description.py#L30

Sadly its actual type is loaded dynamically from the compiled MIB documents (.py), so to know what methods/properties you can use you need to read the actual Cisco* objects in those compiled documents.